# Why is one code faster than the other

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

I appreciate all of the responses, I edited my question and code so they work better.  Apologies for not being clearer before.

I'm new to python and have learned the basics, I'm taking an online class right now and want to know why the second code I will place here is much faster than the first one.  The codes are to get a list of the prime numbers that make up a number and I feel the two codes should be similar in timing, but they are not:

Code 1)

```
def getprime(x):
    j=[]
    for i in range (2,x+1):
        while x%i==0:
                j.append(i)
                x=x/i

    return j
```

2)

```
def get_primes(n):
    result = []
    for i in range(2, n + 1):
        s = 0
        while n % i == 0:
            n = n / i
            s += 1
        if s > 0:
            for k in range(s):
                result.append(i)
            if n == 1:
                return result
```

The number I used was 95485200 and I can see a huge difference in performance which in confirmed for smaller numbers with %%timeit in jupyter notebook, which I find odd since the first few lines of the code are nearly identical.

Thanks.

Comment: A function stops immediately once it executes a `return`. Think about when each function executes its `return`. Also, the loop over `range(2, x)` in the first function uses the original value of `x` even when `x` changes, so `x` reaching `1` doesn't stop the loop.

Comment: (Also, your first function is broken for prime input.)

Comment: You should describe what you're trying to do. Maybe find the prime factors? Test for primality? You're not really doing either. Take a look at [ask] and edit your question

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't be using `/` here, since that returns floats. Instead, use the floor division operator `//`.

Comment: @user2357112 is right; the key is that the first example does not stop the loop when `x` reaches `1`, and the range is one too small for prime input.

Answer (score -2):

The first code checks if the number is divisible by a factor *twice*:
`if x%i==0: ...` and

`while x%i==0: ...`, the first piece of code also creates multiple instances of x: `x=x/i`.

A more efficient code would be:

```
def prime(num):
    if num == 1 or num == 0:
        return False
    prime = True
    for i in range(2, num):
        if num % i == 0:
            prime = False

    return prime
```

Comment: The question isn't completely clear, but the OP isn't just doing a primality test: they want a list of prime factors.